# Latex template, How to remove the boundary line page

Tags: header-footer, cropmarks

Below is my latex code, I want to remove the boundary line. How to change? Thanks
[image]

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\copyrightyear{2015} \pubyear{2015}

\access{Advance Access Publication Date: Day Month Year}
\appnotes{Manuscript Category}

\begin{document}
\firstpage{1}

\subtitle{Subject Section}

\title[short Title]{This is a title}
\author[Sample \textit{et~al}.]{Corresponding Author\,$^{\text{\sfb 1,}*}$, Co-Author\,$^{\text{\sfb 2}}$ and Co-Author\,$^{\text{\sfb 2,}*}$}
\address{$^{\text{\sf 1}}$Department, Institution, City, Post Code, Country and \\
$^{\text{\sf 2}}$Department, Institution, City, Post Code,
Country.}

\corresp{$^\ast$To whom correspondence should be addressed.}

\history{Received on XXXXX; revised on XXXXX; accepted on XXXXX}

\editor{Associate Editor: XXXXXXX}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: The "boundary lines" look like crop marks that seem to come from the document class. Check the documentation for class `bioinfo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`bioinfo`](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bioinformatics/for_authors/submission_online.html) class you are using provides the two options

- `crop`
- `nocrop`

to specify whether you want the crop marks or not. To specify `nocrop`, i.e. no crop marks, change the first line to

```
\documentclass[nocrop]{bioinfo}
```

similarly, to enable the crop marks explicitly, use

```
\documentclass[crop]{bioinfo}
```